# how to use the $ char in sublimetext snippets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sublimetext3, code-snippets

Does any of you know how to use $ char inside a sublimetext snippet? It conflicts with the placeholder syntax.

But what about all that js/jquery stuff like `$(document).ready`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ${1}
});
```

You can clearly see the problem here..
I can't find a solution on docs

Comment: i think you can escape the caracter

Comment: *I can't find a solution on docs*?? [Docs](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html) says `If you want the get a literal $, you have to escape it like this: \$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape special characters like `$` with the backslash key `\`.

Example:

```
\$(document).ready(function(){ 
  ${1} 
});
```

Result:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ${1}
});
```

Comment: It works, thank you, and @RGraham, yes you're right, I didn't see

Answer (score 1):

Escape the dollar sign with a `\`

It should look like this:

```
\$(document).ready(function() {
    ${1}
})
```